# Requirements for using MongoDB transactions

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When creating a new ticket I am trying to use mongo transactions so that I could rollback the transaction if at least one of the "ticket saving process" or "Publishing the ticket created event" fails.

Inside the try catch block I have manually thrown the error (throw new Error('ssomlk caused manual error');) so I could try to test whether the transaction works.

```
const session = await mongoose.startSession();
session.startTransaction();
try {
  await ticket.save({ session });
  throw new Error('ssomlk caused manual error');
  await new TicketCreatedPublisher(natsWrapper.client).publish({
    id: ticket.id,
    title: ticket.title,
    price: ticket.price,
    createdBy: ticket.createdBy,
  });
  await session.commitTransaction();
  session.endSession();
  res.status(201).send(ticket);
} catch (error) {
  session.abortTransaction();
  session.endSession();
  console.log(error);
  res.status(401).send({ error: error.message });
}
```

But I am getting the below error

MongoError: This MongoDB deployment does not support retryable writes. Please add retryWrites=false to your connection string.

According to stackoverflow answers I have included "?retryWrites=false" to my mongo URI but still no luck.

Any advise would be of great help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should be using the pattern described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#transactions-api) (click on nodejs to see the node examples).

Second, transactions require:

- WiredTiger storage engine
- replica set (server 4.0+) or sharded cluster (server 4.2+)

Deployments using mmapv1 storage engine on 4.0 and standalone servers do not support transactions.

Comment: I tried the code but unfortunately the behavior was the same. For transactions on MongoDB 4.2 deployments (replica sets and sharded clusters) you can use that code. sees like my mongodb is standalone

Comment: Transactions are not supported on standalone nodes because they require an oplog.