# MongoDB retryWrites setup code is not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Now, I am trying to develop the transaction session for MongoDB.

- MongoDB version: 4.4.2
- Mongoose version: 5.11.4

The transaction code

```
        const session = await mongoose.startSession();
        session.startTransaction();
        try {
            const result = await storage.create([attachment], { session: session });
            await req.files.newFile.mv(attachment.filePath);
            await session.commitTransaction();
            return res.send(result);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            await session.abortTransaction();
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        } finally {
            session.endSession();
        }
```

When I called this code, that gave me the below error message.

> MongoError: This MongoDB deployment does not support retryable writes. Please add retryWrites=false to your connection string.

So, I add retryWrites=false code in the mongoose connection code.
AS IS

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  poolSize: 10,
});
```

TO BE

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  retryWrites: false,
  poolSize: 10,
});
```

But I still have the same problem...
I am not sure what is the problem.
Please MongoDB expert let me know the solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using mongo transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62349032/using-mongo-transactions)

Answer (score 0):

See [Requirements for using MongoDB transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62349032/requirements-for-using-mongodb-transactions/62351098#62351098) for transaction requirements. You are probably using a standalone deployment.